# An accessToken issue using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, postman

I'm trying to make a GET request from the Facebook [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API), `graph.facebook.com` (using Postman, a Chrome application) to get all events containing the key word  as below:

```
graph.facebook.com/v2.8/search?pretty=0&q=<MY_CITY>&type=event&accessToken=<MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I'm having this response from Facebook:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 104,
        "fbtrace_id": "B5KWVqr7ajK"
    }
}
```

I've rechecked my app_access_Token, and it's fine and works for other requests. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search:

> All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request. You need a **user access token** to execute a search.